# Android: modify JS loaded by a local static html based on selection from list in previous activity

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, templating

Still very much a beginner to Android and Java, so thanks in advance for your patience!

I am trying to find a means of passing a file path (which could be in the form of a simple string or integer) from an activity (in Java) to a WebView (which is rendering a static local html file that is running JS). The issue is complicated by the fact that I am using an AR SDK (Wikitude) and the port to the SDK uses their own customised WebView(which also renders a CameraSurfaceView simultaneously) - controlling their suite is then done in a JS file loaded by the html file.

Any solution is welcome, I am new to Android so don't even know where to begin on this one. In simplest terms, I want to take a chosen option from one activity and use that information to tell my JS file what asset to load/render. If this were a web app you could use some templating to load a dynamic variable into your html (e.g. Using erb in ruby or moustache in JS).

If there is no equivalent for templating Java into a JS file, my current best guess is to write a JSON object using JsonWriter in the activity and subsequently load that file in the JS, if this is indeed the best solution, I am struggling to navigate the internal / external storage of android relative to the assets folder of my app - can anyone shed some light on how I would do that?

I've tried to keep this as general as possible, code can be provided on request.

Comment: Always post your code.  We want to help you here but we can only do that if we see your code.  Also, it would help if your post was more clear about what you want (take out unnecessary details if you want people to help you....).

Answer (score 0):

you can pass chosen option from one activity when you are starting second activity with following code.

//Code to start another activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second_Activity.class);
```

pass the value with intent

```
intent.putExtra("choice1", "choice1");
intent.putExtra("choice1", "choice1");
startActivity(intent);
```

now in second activity onCreate() you can receive these value from intent using following code

```
String choice1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("choice1");
```